# Trying to populate a doc from other model using mongoose returns an empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's the model that has `ref` attribute statement:

```
"use strict"

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const catSchema = new Schema({
  catId: String,
  1: {
    cat: String,
    _id: String,
    subcat: [String],
    _products: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'electronics_model',
      required: true
    }
  }  
});
let catModel = mongoose.model('categories_model', catSchema);
module.exports = catModel;
```

The above model has been instantiated well, no problem in that. `_products` attribute of the above model is given the objectId of `electronics_models` model So that I could populate the entire model.
But the problem is with the route in which mongoose's populate method is been called.
Here's the route:
`localhost:3000/product-by-category?cat=electronics`

code:

```
app.get('/product-by-category', function(req, res){
  db.catModel.find({cat: req.query.cat}).populate({

    path: '_products'

  }).then(function(data){

    res.send(data);

  }).catch(function(err){

    res.send(err);

  });
});
```

It returns an empty array. I couldn't figure out as to what the root cause is.

both the documents i wanted to relate:

**categories_models:**

```
> db.categories_models.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ade178e1b39645d85f0e40d"),
    "1" : {
        "subcat" : [
            "mobiles",
            "laptops",
            "televisions",
            "cameras",
            "mobile accessories"
        ],
        "cat" : "electronics",
        "_id" : "#electronics",
        "_products" : ObjectId("5ade178e1b39645d85f0e40a")
   }
}
```

**electronics_models:**

```
> db.electronics_models.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ade178e1b39645d85f0e40a"),
    "mobiles" : [
        {
            "highlights" : [ ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("5adf05b363b13330b9fef397"),
            "brand" : "asus",
            "model" : "zenfone 2 laser",
            "price" : 9999,
            "currency" : "rs",
            "description" : "very good phone for fairly cheap price"
        }
    ],
    "laptops" : [ ],
    "televisions" : [ ],
    "cameras" : [ ],
    "mobile_accessories" : [ ],
    "searchId" : "#electronic_products",
    "__v" : 5
}
```

Comment: Show two documents you expect to actually be "related" to show that they both in fact have the same `ObjectId` values. Also check you actually registered `'electronics_model'` and not under some other name.

Comment: Yeah, I made sure they both have the same `ObjectId` values. And I've also checked the model name too.

Comment: Can't stress this enough. **"Show two documents"**. Why should we take you on your word? It's a very simple matter to pull up a couple of related documents in the `mongo` shell, and then include the content in your question. That way we can **all** see it, just like we are looking at your data as well. If you want help, then make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: I've updated the question with both the documents.

Comment: Ah. Brain back on. That should be `.populate({ path: '1._products' })`. For some reason you have all those properties embedded under `1`

Comment: Thanks, it worked.